# I'd like to find differences from different table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is what I did:

```
select sum(n.visits) - sum(f.visits) as change_in_visits
from pls_fy2014_pupld14a as f, pls_fy2009_pupld09a as n;
```

The result value from this was : **1551959930404**
This is incorrect result.

However. I am expecting the value of this: **1425930834 - 1591799114**

What did I wrong?

Comment: you make a cross join switch to proper joins and check the result of the select first

Answer (score 0):

`from pls_fy2014_pupld14a as f, pls_fy2009_pupld09a as n` create a **cross join** between the two tables. So if each table has 1000 rows, the result is 1000000 rows. And the `sum()` will be done for that million rows.

As the two tables are unrelated, you need to have two FROM clauses:

```
select (select sum(n.visits)
        from pls_fy2014_pupld14a as f) 
       - 
       (select sum(f.visits)
        from pls_fy2009_pupld09a as n) as change_in_visits
```